# AspNet Core doesn't run in Production on docker ["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production"]

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can't seem to get my aspnet core app to run in docker using ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production, but it works when I change the environment back to Development. In production I can't browse to localhost:port but works okay in dev. My compose file is as below:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    container_name: aspdemo
    image: user/aspdemo
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:22973;
      - 'Logging:LogLevel:Default=Debug'
      - 'Logging:LogLevel:System=Information'
      - 'Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft=Information'
      - 'ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=Server=dbserver;Database=demoDb;User=sa;Password=MyStrong!Pass;'
    ports:
      - "22973:22973"
    networks:
      default: {}
      be:
        aliases:
          - tokenserver

networks:
  be:
    external:
       name: backend
```

AppSettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":     "Server=dbserver;Database=demoDb;User=sa;Password=MyStrong!Pass;"
  },
  "Portal_IP": "http://197.254.91.254",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

AppSettings.Development.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=dbserver;Database=demoDb;User=sa;Password=MyStrong!Pass;"
  },
  "Portal_IP": "http://localhost",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your appSettings.Production.json and appSettings.Development.json ?

Comment: @CelalYildirim check update above

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see your AppSettings.Production.json. If you want to add custom configurations, you can add different appSettings jsons. That is your config file name should be **AppSettings.Production.json**. Because you have changed your environment to production.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=dbserver;Database=demoDb;User=sa;Password=MyStrong!Pass;"
  },
  "Portal_IP": "http://localhost",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for docker-compose.override.yml and override the

environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

To me, the only place I can control which environment you want to deploy.
I have tried to delete docker-compose.override.yml then control everything in docker-compose.yml but it does not work. Looks like we have a bug then?

Austin